# How to fix plugin error appear inside TinyMCE 4 editor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, tinymce-4

I wrote plugin for TinyMCE 4 and added into setup function.

This plugin works well but it shows me a message error float inside editor. I don't know why.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE7tY.png)

This file is called customConfig

```
import Export2Doc  from '../config/plugins/export/plugin';

export default {
  setup: function(editor){
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
      type: 'menubutton',
      text: 'إستخراج الي',
      // icon: false,
      menu: [{
        text: 'Pdf',
        onclick: function() {
          window.open('preview');
        }
      }, 
      {
        text: 'Docx',
        onclick: function(){
          Store.dispatch('getDocumentContents').then( response =>{
            let contentString = "";
            Store.state.documents.documentContents.forEach(element => {
              if(element.content != ""){
                console.log(element.content, element, response);
                contentString += '<br style="page-break-after: always; clear: both" />'+element.content;
              }

            });


            Export2Doc.excute(contentString, 'atroha');
          });
        },
      }]
    });
  }
}
```

Then inside editor it looks like this :

```
import customConfig from "./customConfig";

const config = {
    selector: "#editor",
  directionality: "rtl",
  branding: false,
  height: 500,
  theme: "modern",
  // toolbar: 'mybutton',
  plugins:
    "mybutton fullscreen charmap hr anchor searchreplace wordcount pagebreak print preview image table "+
    "anchor advlist lists tinymcespellchecker a11ychecker "+
    "imagetools mediaembed  link contextmenu directionality "+
    "save autosave",
  // toolbar1:
  //   "table | image | bold link | alignleft aligncenter alignright  | ltr rtl |  numlist bullist | outdent indent | references | threads",
  // fullscreen pagebreak preview |
  // plugins:
  //  "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker"+ 
  //   "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking"+
  //   "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor",
  // toolbar2: " media | forecolor backcolor emotions | help", 
  toolbar1: ' table insertfile undo redo mybutton save | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft | ltr rtl | aligncenter alignright alignjustify '+
    '| bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons | references | threads',
  image_advtab: true,
  // language: "ar_EG",
  menubar: true,

  autosave_ask_before_unload: true,
   setup: customConfig.setup,
}

export default config;
```

I try to hide the message but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

That error message means that TinyMCE is looking for your plugin (mybutton) in the place it looks for all of its standard plugins and the plugin is not found in that location.

The issue is that you have not actually created a plugin for TinyMCE in the code you show - you appear to create toolbar button via code.

To move this forward you have two options...

1. Use the setup function in your TinyMCE configuration and create the toolbar button in that function.  You can then add the toolbar button to your toolbar configuration setting.  In this scenario you are not creating a plugin so you don't add anything to the plugins configuration setting.
2. Create a proper TinyMCE plugin and load that plugin using the plugins configuration setting.  The plugin can register a toolbar button on the toolbar as it loads.

**If you choose option 1...**
Assuming your code is wired together correctly you can just remove your attempt to load a plugin called `mybutton` (there is no such plugin) and instead add `mybutton` to the `toolbar1` configuration setting.  This will explicitly add your defined toolbar button to the TinyMCE toolbar.

**If you choose option 2...**
As you are using the TinyMCE Cloud platform to load TinyMCE you need to use the `external_plugins` configuration option to load your custom plugin from some location on your server.  You can't host a custom plugin on the TinyMCE Cloud platform and just adding a plugin to the plugins configuration option will tell TinyMCE to load it from the same place it loads all its other plugins.

If you want to look at this second option here is the documentation on how to create a proper plugin for TinyMCE:

- TinyMCE 5: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/
- TinyMCE 4: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/advanced/creating-a-plugin/

Comment: Thank you bro , I need to use your second option but I am using ```tinymce version 4``` and documentation related with ```tinymce version 5```

Comment: @Omda there is an equivalent page on the documentation site for TinyMCE 4.  I added a link to it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Fromin for your response I am trying to make plugin with second option you earlier mentioned.

Comment: where can i put my plugin, for example 
```
1 -  /tinymce/plugins/example/plugin.js
2-  tinymce.PluginManager.add('example', function(editor, url)...
3- setup
4- init
```

Comment: You have to put it somewhere on your web server and reference it via `external_plugins` such that the browser can load the files at runtime.  It does not matter where you put the files as long as they can be accessed at runtime by the browser.

Comment: i put this file into plugins/example/plugin.js

and then called like this :
```
external_plugins: {
    'example': "plugins/example/plugin",
  },
```
and i have get error  "undefiend tinymce"  
what can I do ?